# Как убрать границы псевдоэлемента?

Tags: html, css

Как убрать границы псевдоэлемента? Пока псевдоэлемент без бордера все норм

```css
.btn-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
   
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(to top ,#a40202,#f73b3b);
    color: #fff;
    
    margin-left: 120px;
    height: 85px;
    width: 101px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
    border-top:1px solid #bf3a3a;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fe5858;
    border-right: 1px solid #bf3a3a;
    z-index: 1000;
    
}
.btn-arrow i.flaticon-shopping109 {

    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color:#481214;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ff6c66;
    

}


.btn-arrow:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: -25px;
    top: 51%;
    background:linear-gradient(to top left,#a40202,#f73b3b); 
    width: 50px;
    height: 38px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    
    z-index: 1;
    transform:rotate(65deg) skewX(40deg);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fe5858;
    border-left:1px solid #bf3a3a;

}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn-arrow" id="f_default">
    <i class="flaticon-shopping109"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html><head>
    <style>
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    


    <style>
        .btn-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
   
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(to top ,#a40202,#f73b3b);
    color: #fff;
    
    margin-left: 120px;
    height: 85px;
    width: 101px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
    border-top:1px solid #bf3a3a;
   
    border-right: 1px solid #bf3a3a;
    z-index: 1000;
    
}
.btn-arrow i.flaticon-shopping109 {

    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color:#481214;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ff6c66;
    

}


.btn-arrow:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: -25px;
    top: 51%;
    background:linear-gradient(to top left,#a40202,#f73b3b); 
    width: 50px;
    height: 38px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    
    z-index: 1;
    transform:rotate(65deg) skewX(40deg);

  

}
    </style>


    <a href="#" class="btn-arrow" id="f_default">
    <i class="flaticon-shopping109"></i>
</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    </script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: так мне нужны эти бордеры))

Comment: Вопрос решен или? Не могу вас понять. сделайте скрин в паинте что вам нужно укажите

Answer (score 0):

```
border-bottom: 0px solid #fe5858;
border-left:0px solid #bf3a3a
```

Comment: я не о бордерах говорил.тут еле заметные 1пиксельные очертания контура объекта.

Comment: ссылку на сайт дайте или загрузите код

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте прописать `outline: 0px none;`

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Это Хром так отрисовывает немного неточно. Либо, там длобные пиксели получаются. Можно попробовать поподбирать значения, чтобы получилось лучше.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .btn-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
   
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(to top ,#a40202,#f73b3b);
    color: #fff;
    
    margin-left: 120px;
    height: 85px;
    width: 101px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
    border-top:1px solid #bf3a3a;
   
    border-right: 1px solid #bf3a3a;
    z-index: 1000;
    
}
.btn-arrow i.flaticon-shopping109 {

    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color:#481214;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ff6c66;
    

}


.btn-arrow:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: -25px;
    top: 51%;
    background:linear-gradient(to top left,#a40202,#f73b3b); 
    width: 50px;
    height: 38px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    
    z-index: 1;
    transform:rotate(65deg) skewX(40deg);

    border-left:1px solid #bf3a3a;

}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="btn-arrow" id="f_default">
    <i class="flaticon-shopping109"></i>
</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```